# Excel suddenly parses CSV wrong

Tags: excel

I am used to opening CSV files in Excel, but now, regardless of the CSV content, it always appears as a single-column table with one string that includes commas.

For example, this is the CSV file content:

```
this,is,an,example
123,456,789,101112
234,567,8910,111213
```

And this is how it appears when opening the CSV file in Excel:

[image: Excel fails to parse CSV]

Note that I haven't changed any configuration, it just suddenly happened, and this behavior repeats for any file-content that I am trying to open, which was parsed correctly just until several minutes ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my file has been saved in UTF-16 encoding, after redirecting PowerShell command output into it. The encoding kept being UTF-16 when I changed the content in the text editor, which made me think that something in Excel went wrong.

**Changing the file encoding to UTF-8 solved it**.